# Why wont my VS2010 let me add 'WebInvoke' from System.ServiceModel.Web?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I don't know if im missing something but I have added a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web from a web site project in VS2010 but I am not able to access that namespace in the code. I just cannot get to it, and even though when I added the reference it came up in the list, when its added, the namespace doesnt even come up on the objects tab when I search for it!! arrgg how annoying!

I am using Web Site project type in visual studio.

1. What is going on why cant I access this namespace even though I have added it?
2. Where does this project type keep a list of references to the dll's? It used to just coopy the dll into the bin and keep it in the csproj file but there is no csproj file with this project type....

I have checked that the target framework is 4 not 4 + client profile or anything else...

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is to make sure that the Target Framework is set to `.NET Framework 4` (or possibly 3.5).

As far as question 2 (assuming I understand the question ), the list of references can be seen in the project properties.  The first item in the `Property Pages` is the list of references.  And (**edit**) based on the comment, the web.config file contains the actual list of references (search for `add assembly`).

Comment: yep already checked that....where does this project type store the physical list of references?